# batch file to concatenate all csv files in a subfolder for all subfolders

Tags: batch-file, concatenation, subdirectory

I have a batch script to concatenate all of the `.csv` files in my directory into one text file:

```
set writepath=filename.txt
type *.csv > %writepath% 2>&1
EXIT
```

My problem is I need to do this for dozens of directories.  Is there a way I can get this script to run on each subfolder in my directory so that the `filename.txt` for that specific directory is stored in each subdirectory?

I've been trying to do this with a  `for /d /r` loop but I'm stuck.  I don't quite understand the syntax of the for loop in batch.  Any guidance is appreciated.

I consider myself a novice with batch scripting so please give as much description/explanation as you can.

Thanks!

Comment: in batch, details matter. Show your `for /d /r` loop, so we can help you with it.

Comment: (just guessing...) you should find the "modifier" section of `for /?` helpful.

Comment: Also just guessing: `for /D /R "D:\path\to\root\dir" %%I in ("*.csv") do ( ... )` (omitting the root path assumes the current working directory; in between the parentheses after `in`, only state a file mask, but nothing else (no absolute or relative path stuff)...

Comment: I would also suggest that you don't really want StdErr, (`2>&1`), directing to `filename.txt` either!

Comment: @Compo: `type` with wildcards writes the filenames to STDERR (unusual, unexpected, unintuitive, but alas - if you don't want just the contents but also their source, you *have* to include STDERR)

Comment: Thanks @Stephan, I didn't know that. It's nice to know, although I would probably not use `Type` for this anyhow!

Comment: Hi All thanks for the feedback. Since I posted this I ended up moving to powershell because I also needed to script in a way to unzip several folders at once and I couldn't find a way to do that from a command line without downloading files.  I'm pretty close to getting what I need done in powershell - just figuring out how to manipulate the get-content function to make the concatenated file look the way I want it.  Thanks again.