# combine all csv in various subfolders in pandas or in powershell/terminal and create a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, merge

I have individual csv files within each subfolders of subfolders. From year to months, and within each month folder are day folders, and within each day, is the individual csv. I would like to combine all of the individual csv into one and create a pandas df.

In the tree diagram, it looks like this:

[image]

I tried this approach below but nothing was created:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'~/root/up/to/the/folder/2022'
alldata = glob.glob(path + "each*.csv")
alldata.head()
```

I initially had it just looking for "each*.csv" files but realized there is something missing in between in order to get individual csv within each folder. Then maybe, a for loop will work. like loop through each folder within each subfolder, but that is where I am stucked right now.

The answer to this: [Combining separate daily CSVs in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60923806/combining-separate-daily-csvs-in-pandas) shows files that are in the same folder.

I tried to make sense on this answer: [batch file to concatenate all csv files in a subfolder for all subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398969/batch-file-to-concatenate-all-csv-files-in-a-subfolder-for-all-subfolders), but it just won't click on me.

I also tried the following as suggested in [Python importing csv files within subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68377976/python-importing-csv-files-within-subfolders)

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = '<Insert Path>'
file_extension = '.csv'
csv_file_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(file_extension):
            file_path = os.path.join(root, name)
            csv_file_list.append(file_path)

dfs = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in csv_file_list]
```

but nothing is showing, I think there is something wrong with the path to redirect as shown in the tree above.

Or maybe there is a following step I need to do because when I ran `dfs.head()` it says `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'head'`

Comment: Right now `dfs` is a list of dfs. If you wanted it to be the concatenation of all dfs you can use `big_df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in csv_file_list))`

Comment: @mitoRibo thanks, it worked. When I first ran the big_df, I had an issue with `Nothing to concatenate`, but I changed my path to a direct path rather than using `~/path` as I had originally.

Answer (score 3):

The following should work:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

csv_folder = Path('.')  # path to your folder, e.g. to `2022`
df = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(p) for p in csv_folder.glob('**/*.csv'))
```

Alternatively, if you prefer you can also use `glob.glob('**/*.csv', recursive=True)` instead of the `Path.glob` method.

Comment: Hi @asdf, thanks this worked too! It is good to have two possible answers to verify each other's reasults.